# Precompiled assets not being used

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nginx

I deployed my Rails application to an nginx server. When i go to the Page i can see the precompiled js and css assets including their fingerprints in the filename. I can also navigate to them in the browser but none of the js functions work. Neither the one that come along with CKEditor or Bootstrap-Datepicker nor the functions i've written by my self.

Safari returns `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: CKEDITOR`

Firefox: `ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined`

In local development mode it works just fine. The really confusing part for me is, that the precompiled css is working perfectly.

I'm using coffeScript with the coffee-rails gem (v. 4.1.1) and jquery-rails (v 4.1.0)

For the deploy i use capistrano (v 3.4.0)

Rails version is 4.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind after reordering the required files in `app/assets/javascript/application.js` the error was no longer there.

Before i had:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require ckeditor/init
```

And now the working order is:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

So I moved the `//= require ckeditor/init` above the `//= require_tree .`